# Perform action if app is not used for specified time in android

Tags: android

I have an android app in development which enables the user to protect the data inside the app by entering a password or pin. Is there a method to check if the app hasn't been used for lets say 10 minutes to then change a setting in the app prefs file.

I was thinking of maybe a service, or a class within the app that runs instead another thread with a timer but not sure if this would be suitable.

Another method, I was thinking is there a way so that when the user presses the home button, the home button does its normal task of return to the android home screen but it also changes a setting within the apps prefs file.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: How about saving the time in `onPause` (when your app goes into the background) and then seeing how long it has been since you got put into to the background when `onResume` is called (when your app becomes the foreground app again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joseph Earl comment on my question is the answer. Works perfectly.

Use the onPause method and get the time of android and save it to the app config.

then use the onResume to get the current time of android and the time from the config and get the time in minutes.

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
private long lastTimeUpdating;
```

all where you have an actions

```
lastTimeUpdating = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and you must have a thread which is updating every 50 milliseconds, in this thread check this

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeUpdating >= 5 * 60 * 1000) {
   /*change your settings here*/
}
```

Comment: I would guess it's a real nightmare to handle all situations in which application has been used and reset timer accordingly.

Comment: I don't see any solution at the moment, so I have proposed this solution.

Comment: Actually, I don't see either. There are other ways for timing of course but the biggest problem remains, as I see it, it's very difficult to reset timer every time application has been used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chronometer control for timing an action.

Use the **start() and stop()** methods, to determine state.

Example:

```
final Chronometer timer = 
    (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.Chronometer1);
long base1 = timer.getBase();
timer.setBase(0);
timer.start();
```

listen for changes using the Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener interface